# JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 error in HTTPS POST response

Tags: java, json, restful-authentication, connectivity

I am trying to POST HTTPS request to one of the client's server. In turn the response which is returned back from the server is `missing "{" from the JSON response.`

When the client is testing they are receiving proper response.

Can you please help me out on debugging whats an issue with the code content. The same issue persist of missing "<" character in
XML response while changing the header to "Accept", "application/xml".

```
 // Request headers that needs to be passed

     public Object generateHttpHeader(String requestType, IYodRobot pRobot, Object request) {       

            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Connection"," Keep-Alive");
            headers.put("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)");
            headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            headers.put("Cookie", "Aggregator=stuff");
     // Headers generated that need to be passed.

            return headers; 
        }
     // Posting request 
     protected String postRequestLocal(Object generateHttpHeader){      
     URL url;
            HttpsURLConnection urlConn;
            //Generating HTTPS connection object
            OutputStreamWriter wout = null;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            StringBuffer ResponseData = new StringBuffer();
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            String contents = "";
            String reasonForRetry = "";
            String URL = "https://XXXXXXX/service/Servlet";
            //Constructing request
            String request = "UID=" + "abcdefgh" + "&KEY=" + "12344";

            System.out.println("2^^^^^^^ URL is: " + URL);
            System.out.println("Request is ::"+request);

            try {
               //URL connection creation
                url = new URL(URL);
                urlConn = (javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection)
                url.openConnection();


                urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);


                String  clientKeyStore = "XXXXXXXX";
                String  password = "XXXXXX";
                // 2- WAY SSL Connectivity 
                urlConn.setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory(new File("/XXX/XXX/XX/XXX/" + clientKeyStore), password));

                urlConn.setDoInput(true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConn.connect();

                HashMap<String, String> headers = (HashMap<String, String>) generateHttpHeader;

                System.out.println("2^^^^^^^^^^^^^printing url connection " + urlConn.toString());

                for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> headerIter = headers.entrySet().iterator(); 

     headerIter.hasNext();) {
                    System.out.println(" In here.......................");
                    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = headerIter.next();
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    System.out.println("2^^^^^^^ printing key " + entry.getKey().toString() + "  value is" + 

     entry.getValue().toString());
                }
     //Hashmap for request headers that needs to be passed`enter code here`
                Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = urlConn.getRequestProperties();
                YDataLogger.out("2^^^^^^^^^^Request Header Fields is: "+ requestHeaders);
                YDataLogger.out("urlConn.getRequestMethod"+urlConn.getRequestMethod());



                    wout = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
                    System.out.println("2^^^^^^^^^checkpoint 8");
                    wout.write(request);
                    System.out.println("2^^^^^^^^^wout" + wout.toString());
                    wout.flush();
                    wout.close();

                /*
                 * Getting the soap error message if we have error.
                 */
                System.out.println("2^^^ Trying to print the fault");
                System.out.println("2^^^^^^ urlConngetResponseCode--->" + urlConn.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("2^^^^^^ urlConngetResponseMessage--->" + urlConn.getResponseMessage());

                if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());              
                } else if(urlConn.getResponseCode() == 500) {
                    throw new SiteApplicationErrorException("Server down", urlConn.getResponseMessage());
                }
                    else {
                    isr = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getErrorStream());
                }

                Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders = urlConn.getHeaderFields();
                System.out.println("2^^^^^^^^^^Response Header Fields is: "+responseHeaders);

                System.out.println("2^^^^^^^ response header---"+urlConn.getHeaderFields());


                    br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String s = null;
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    ResponseData.append(s);
                }
     //Diconnecting URL connecttion


                urlConn.disconnect();
                /*
                 * getting the soap Data/Message if we have error.
                 */

                Date end = new Date();
                System.out.println("2^^^ Properties" + urlConn.getRequestProperties());
                System.out.println("2^^^^^" + end.toLocaleString());
                contents = ResponseData.toString();



            } 
 //catching exception
 catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("2^^^^^ getStackTrace-->\n" + getStackTrace(ex));
                reasonForRetry = ex.getMessage();
```

Printing stack trace in case of https failure

```
                if (ex.getMessage().contains(
                        "server returned http response code: 500")) {
                    throw new SiteApplicationErrorException(
                            "2^^^^Top Level Error - Returned HTTP response code: 500 :: Exact error"
                                    + ex.getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("2^^^^^ getStackTrace-->\n" + getStackTrace(ex));
                    throw new GeneralException(ex.toString() + "\n"
                            + ex.getMessage());
                }

            } finally {
                if (wout != null) {
                    wout.close();
                }
                if (isr != null) {
                    isr.close();
                }
            }
     // Printing the response returned back
            System.out.println("2^^^^^^^^^Contents  : "+contents);
     }
```

Comment: why is there a `>` on **every** line?

Comment: Apologies, typo error. corrected

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the webservice expects the parameters UID and KEY to be passed as JSON (or XML), not application/x-www-form-urlencoded.